# Most common way to implement predefined classes.

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm working on an iPhone game that has a bunch of monsters. Each monster has a name, up to 4 different attacks, and a few sprites that represent its state. I have a monster class set up and it works really well. I've managed to make two monsters battle and all that jazz and it works. My game though is going to have a predefined group of monsters in it that all have different statistics and I'm kind of struggling to come up with the best way to accomplish this. I have two ideas so far.

**Ideas:**

- Make a class whose only purpose is to define all the monsters available in the game using the Monster class.
- Subclass the monster class for each and every monster I need. Even though none of them will really add anything to the monster class.

The benefits for the second method are that it would be easier to make ties between two different monsters (like evolution trees).

What do you guys think would be the best way to do this? I'm leaning towards the second method. Is the another method that I'm missing?

Comment: It would help if you shared some sample code from your Monster class, as well as some code that uses a Monster object.

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals i believe he is asking about methodology not a sample code itself.

Comment: It really doesn't sound as if these should be different classes from the way you describe them.  If only the values of their properties change, that sort of defines multiple objects of the same class.  It's only when you start having different behavior and different **types** of state that classes usually come into play.

Comment: @Phillip I agree I just couldn't think of a way to bring together evolution trees or other direct ties between different monsters without subclassing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common pattern for this sort of problem is to create a [factory class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_pattern), which is close to your first idea. You make a single class, called perhaps MonsterFactory, whose job it is to manufacture instances of the Monster class for use elsewhere. If you structure the factory properly, it can even handle the evolution-tree sort of thing well.

An additional benefit of a factory is that it abstracts away the details of storing information about your monsters. For example, you could hardcode the first five or ten monsters' worth of info into the program to test it, but later reimplement the factory to use a database or file on disk for larger volumes of monsters. As long as your factory API remains constant, your Monster class doesn't have to care about those details; it's all in the factory.

Comment: Ah this looks promising. I also love the idea of reading from a database or file. I knew there had to be a way to abstract it like this. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

> Even though none of them will really add anything to the monster class.
>
> The benefits for the second method are that it would be easier to make ties between two different monsters (like evolution trees)

Answered your own question.